# Build error when setting environment variable

Tags: ember-cli

When running `ember build --environment staging` I get a build error. In config/environment.js I have a condition looking for staging so I can change the baseUrl to our staging services. But when I try and build with the environment set I get the following error:

`You must pass a file to 'EmberApp::import'. For directories specify them to the constructor under the 'trees' option.`

Is this a problem with ember-cli or do I need to declare my environment in my Brocfile somehow?

Comment: It seems it's not yet possible: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/662#issuecomment-46561656.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ember currently has issues with custom environments, try using shell variables for modifying behaviour inside single Ember production environment.

If you call ember like `DEPLOY_ENV=staging ember build --environment=production` then you will be able to access `DEPLOY_ENV` shall variable inside all JS files via `process.env.DEPLOY_ENV` and modify their behaviour accordingly.

I personally like decoupling deploy environment from application environment, cause it allows to have a staging server which is just like production.